# Is it a convention to start filename with 'use' when naming Vue 3 js modules?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I've started using the new Vue 3 for months, there seems to be no style guide for new Vue 3 since the official release in September. So far I just see the most comprehensive documentation here:

[Vue Composition api](https://composition-api.vuejs.org/)

I find that the example js module names usually have the prefix "use" in the documentation and in some online tutorials. Foe example, *useMousePosition.js*. I just wonder if it's a convention and is there any meaning behind the prefix "use"?

And one more question, I keep most "non-UI" logics in the js files, and UI-related data and methods in vue files.  This was also my approach when doing in the old Vue 2. Is this a proper way also when working in Vue3 ?

Thank you!

Comment: `is there any meaning` yea, it means *to employ for some purpose* - but it has no significance to how it works, like all conventions it's a convention and not a rule

Comment: From the [official Vue 3 docs](https://v3.vuejs.org): [*Style Guide*](https://v3.vuejs.org/style-guide), [*Composition API Guide*](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-introduction.html), and [*Composition API Reference*](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/composition-api.html)

Answer (score 5):

The `Composition API RFC` covers this in [this section](https://github.com/vuejs/composition-api-rfc/blob/master/index.md#logical-concerns-vs-option-types).

**Excerpt**

> Notice how all the logic related to the create new folder feature is
> now collocated and encapsulated in a single function. The function is
> also somewhat self-documenting due to its descriptive name. This is
> what we call a composition function. **It is a recommended convention to
> start the function's name with use to indicate that it is a
> composition function**. This pattern can be applied to all the other
> logical concerns in the component

Comment: I don't like it, a prefix like `use` really can lead to confusion and misunderstandings about a functions purpose.